# Getting sibling JSON data with Handlebars, where a single object has no parent index key, but multiple items have an index key?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've come across an interesting, but annoying situation with some data i'm grabbing from an API that sort of exposes the downfalls of using a templating language like Handlebars. (*Helpers, Helpers everywhere!*)

**Is there a clean way to handle the following situation. Essentially, if a JSON object only has only has one sibling, it's not wrapped with a key, but if it returns multiple, they're wrapped with a key.**

So below we have an example where ingredient has one sibling, and it's returned without being wrapped. The second object returns 2 ingredients, and so they're wrapped with an index key.

I can't really do anything about the way the data looks, i've just got to be able to handle it.

I'm assuming a helper is the way to go, but i'm hoping there's a neat trick for handling the following situation in order to catch both depending on what data is returned. I'd also prefer to do it using pure Handlbars if possible (*without the help of Ember etc*).

If anyone can help, i'd appreciate it!

Scenario 1:

```
"food":{
  "ingredient":{
    "name":"Cucumber",
    "weight":"5",
    "cost":"1",
  }
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
"food":{
 "ingredient":{
  "1":{
     "name":"Cheese",
     "weight":"10",
     "cost":"2"
  },
  "2":{
     "name":"Tomato",
     "weight":"20",
     "cost":"0.5"
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

This `packageResponse()` function will return the `ingredient` data the same way for each scenario you mentioned:

```
/*  ===================
    SUPPORT FUNCTION(s)
    =================== */
function isKeyNumeric(key){
    var test = Number(key);
    if(isNaN(test))
        return false;
    return true;
}


/*  =============
    MAIN FUNCTION
    =============   */
function packageResponse(ingredient){

    var ingredients = {}
    var count = 0

    for(var i in ingredient){

        //  Breakpoint in case we get a prototype property
        if( !ingredient.hasOwnProperty(i) ) continue;

        //  Test for what method to use
        if( isKeyNumeric(i) ){
            //  Add the wrapped ingredient
            ingredients[count++] = ingredient[i]
        }else{
            //  Add the unwrapped ingredient
            ingredients[0] = ingredient
            break
        }//endifelse
    }//endfor

    return ingredients
}//endfunction
```

---

### Test:

```
/*  =========
    TEST DATA
    =========   */
var response_one = {"food":{
    "ingredient":{
        "name":"Cucumber",
        "weight":"5",
        "cost":"1",
        }
    }
}

var response_two = {"food":{
    "ingredient":{
        "1":{
            "name":"Cheese",
            "weight":"10",
            "cost":"2"
            },
        "2":{
            "name":"Tomato",
            "weight":"20",
            "cost":"0.5"
            }
        }
    }
}

/*  ===========
    TEST OUTPUT
    =========== */
console.log( packageResponse(response_one.food.ingredient) )
console.log( packageResponse(response_two.food.ingredient) )
```

---

### Output:

The above code generates this console output:

***First Log:***

```
0: Object
  cost: "1"
  name: "Cucumber"
  weight: "5"
```

***Second Log***

```
0: Object
  cost: "2"
  name: "Cheese"
  weight: "10"

1: Object
  cost: "0.5"
  name: "Tomato"
  weight: "20"
```

Comment: Ohhh. Yeah, this looks good! Don't suppose you can give me a little help converting that to a Handlebars helper? e.g `{{#eachObject}}{{/eachObject}}`  would return each object. Really appreciate it!